# Express- Mi middleware de manejo de errores no funciona

Tags: nodejs, express, middleware

[![Adjunto como en la terminal se muestra que el error no es manejado][1]][1]Estoy tratando de hacer mi middleware de errores, pero este no capta los errores, dejo el codigo

```
app.use("/", ruters);
app.use(errorHandler);
```

el import funciona correctamente, pero de todas formas no me ingresa al errorHandler, adjunto el errorHandler

````
import EErrors from "../services/errors/enums.js";

export default (err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Ingreso Al err Handler");
  switch (err.status) {
    case EErrors.INVALID_TYPES_ERROR:
      res
        .status(err.status)
        .send({ status: err.status, response: err.response });
      break;
    default:
      res.status(err.status).send({ status: "err", response: "Unhandled error" });
  }
};```




Intente poner el handler arriba de las rutas pero no funciono, tambien trate de poner directamente el middleware en app.use((err,req,res,next)), agradeceria sus respuestas


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVJdd.png
````

Answer (score 0):

El error handler debe ser la última línea en tu servidor de express, El middleware de manejo de errores se define al final, después de otras llamadas de rutas y app.use() (https://expressjs.com/es/guide/error-handling.html)

```
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.info(`Application listening on port: ${port}`);
})

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // logic
});
```

Existen otro tipo de errores de aplicación, que no se encuentran controlados por el código, se pueden capturar de esta forma:

```
process
  .on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
    console.error(reason, 'Unhandled Rejection at Promise', p);
  })
  .on('uncaughtException', err => {
    console.error(err, 'Uncaught Exception thrown');
    process.exit(1);
  });
```